# error sql query with c#

Tags: c#, vb.net, vb.net-to-c#

Please how to convert this line of code:

```
 Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter("select * from View_1 where Words_Sh like N'" & Me.txbSearch.Text & "%'", con)
```

in c#

```
  SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select * from View_1 where Words_Sh like N'" + this.txbSearch..Text + "%'", con);
// this line => error
```

Comment: You are opening yourself up to so SQL Injection attacks. You need to sanitise that data. Also, what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: it not search the listbox thatI wont to search.(Also I have a database)// I dont care about SQL Injection attacks, I just need to finish this homework

Comment: @BSoD_ZA you shouldn't attempt to fix injection by sanitizing: that is doing it wrong. You *parameterize*. Very different.

Comment: The `..Text` looks suspicious. However: please tell us exactly what the error message *says*. And btw, if you "don't care about SQL injection", personally I'd give you an "F-" (at best)

Answer (score 5):

You should alwasy use [`parameterized queries`](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/04/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death.html). This kind of string concatenations are open for [`SQL Injection`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

And you should remove the extra dot in `this.txbSearch..Text`

---

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from View_1 where Words_Sh LIKE ' + @txbSearch + '%'", con);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txbSearch", this.txbSearch.Text);
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, con);
```

Comment: it give me some errors. Have you a code how to search a list box where txbSearch_TextChanged

Comment: that would post a query every time the user presses a key -NOT ideal...consider a button for the user to press when they are done typing.

Comment: @JonAlba saying "it give me some errors" is completely useless to us. Tell us what errors. Exactly. Verbatim.

Comment: @Soner very minor, but the original search was only open (wildcard) on the right - not both sides.

Comment: @MarcGravell Ups totally missed that. Sorry. Updated.